# I do not understand description of android.graphics.Matrix.setValues() in reference page

Tags: android, graphics, matrix

I'm having trouble understanding the description of the behaviour of the method setValues() in class android.graphics.Matrix. In the overview of [Android developer's reference page for the Matrix class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) says that the class holds a 3x3 matrix.

> The Matrix class holds a 3x3 matrix for transforming coordinates.

But in the [description of the setValues(float[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setValues%28float%5B%5D%29) method, it says,

> Copy 9 values from the array into the matrix. Depending on the implementation of Matrix, these may be transformed into 16.16 integers in the Matrix, such that a subsequent call to getValues() will not yield exactly the same values.

I'm not sure what 16.16 integers is. If this was some kind of typo and simply meant 16 integers, I assume that it means that it could be transformed into a 4x4 matrix. But this also doesn't make sense to me. It is explicitly said that the Matrix class holds a 3x3 matrix. Where is this coming from? Could it be a warning about the float array passed as the parameter which is supposedly an array of the contents of another matrix could be a 4x4 matrix? I am confused. Can anybody give me a clear understanding on this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the 16.16 does not refer to the matrix in question but the data in each cell of the matrix

16.16 integers have a 16 bit integer part, and a 16 bit fractional part (16 bits before and 16 bits after the decimal point) and are fixed point instead of floating point.

I believe you get better performance from using 16.16 integers than floating point and they have a fixed point.